# Balance is still stuck at 5000

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I've attempted everything I could think of and my balance will not change no matter what. My code currently is:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Session.setDefault('num', Random.fraction());
  Session.setDefault('bal', 5000)

  Template.hello.helpers({
    num: function () {
      return Session.get('num');
    }
  });

  Template.Balance.helpers({
    bal: function () {
      return Session.get('bal');
    }
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {
      Session.set("num", Random.fraction());
    }
  });

   Template.TrueFalse.helpers({
  'trueFalse': function(){
    return( Session.get('num') > 0.5 ? true : false )
  }
});

Template.Balance.events({
  'click button': function() {
    if ( Session.get('num') > 0.5 ) {
      Session.set('bal', Session.get('bal') + 1);
    } else {
      Session.set('bal', Session.get('bal') - 1);
    }
  }
});

}
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
  });
}
```

I tried some previous solutions out but none seemed to work.

I think it might have something to do with the fact that the random number is generated, and checked to see if it's greater or less than .5 at the same time due to both functions being 'click button', but I wouldn't know how to fix that anyway.

Can someone just code the fix, and i'll figure out what you did?

Thanks.

BTW, this is the HTML file if it helps:

```
<head>
  <title>RNG</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>{{> Balance}}</h1>

  {{> hello}}

  <h1>{{> TrueFalse}}</h1>
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{num}} times.</p>
</template>

<template name="TrueFalse">
    {{#if trueFalse}}
        You Win!
    {{else}}
        You Lose!
    {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="Balance">
    Balance: {{bal}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used really used Meteor, but here's what it looks like: when you define events for a template, the event selector only matches *within* the template. So the `click button` event that is bound within the Balance template never is triggered, because there's no button in the Balance template.

You can update the balance inside the Hello template's `click button` event:

```
  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {
      Session.set("num", Random.fraction());
      if ( Session.get('num') > 0.5 ) {
        Session.set('bal', Session.get('bal') + 1);
      } else {
        Session.set('bal', Session.get('bal') - 1);
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: You're definitely right about the need to update the balance inside hello's template, but it didn't work. I not exactly sure why. Is there a way to, instead of having it run when the button is clicked, have it run shortly after?

Comment: Ignore all of what i just said :P The solution worked. Thank you so much. I'm not lying, i've been trying to solve this for 3 days.